# Printing numbers column by column

Tags: c++

I am trying to print numbers column by column.

I am trying to run 50 simulations that will produce a list of numbers. For every simulation, the length of such list is unknown.

For every simulation I want to print the numbers down a column.

When the next simulation starts I want the program to go back up to the top of the file and start printing the list down without entering into the previous list.

All I can find are ways to print the numbers by row, but I will not know the numbers down the row unless I do all the simulations.

Any advice would be much appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please read this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask .  This is not a "please do my work for me" site.  What have you tried?  Show us some code or something, or prepare for downvotes.

Answer (score 4):

You have a few choices:

1. Write each sim result to a separate file and collate later;
2. Hold all results in memory until finished;
3. After each simulation, read the existing file, and output it again with the new results added in;
4. Knowing the number of simulations you intend to produce, write results in binary and leave padding for those that are not yet done.

I would probably go with 1.

Comment: Yeah I was thinking about that. I will try that, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

By "goes back to the top of the file", do you actually mean [rewind](http://beej.us/guide/bgc/output/html/multipage/fseek.html) the [file pointer](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/) to access memory starting at the beginning of the file? I will assume that's what you meant. Since you want the first input after the last output, then you can run your simulations and print them in reverse order, or simply call the appropriate library functions as you need them.

Comment: I guess. I am obviously not very good at this. I just want the numbers to be printed in columns, like so:

Comment: i cant show what i mean in this box.

Comment: Go ahead and post here, that's fine.